# tesseract recognition low confidence or wrong result

Tags: javascript, tesseract

Im working with Tesseract library.

I have tried the [demo](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) and I got the expected results correctly.

but when I tried it on my localmachine I got a way different result.

this is the image Im using [image]

and this is my code

```
Tesseract.recognize(image_object), {lang: 'eng'}).progress(function  (p) { console.log('progress', p)    })
   .then(function (result) { console.log('result', result) })
```

the result from the demo is 0.08 and the result from my localmachine is 003

EDIT:
here is another image we can try:

[image: image_2]

this one works 100% on the demo, but local machine result is "o ts"

Comment: The demo page shows `003` for me!

Comment: If you change the demo from English to Russian, it then shows `008`

Comment: @sadrzadehsina thats still not the correct answer

Comment: @sadrzadehsina I added a new image that we can test on

Comment: @user3169 check my code above, very simple code. and Im using version v1.0.14

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: This is very strange! Same image gives me 003 first then 0.08 and now it is again 003.
(both in demo page and my local machine)